# Modifying select statement based on textfield values

Tags: java, mysql, database, jdbc, prepared-statement

I have four text fields for `FirstName`, `LastName`, `ID`, and `department`. I let the user search for any student record by entering data in the text field. When the user hits submit button, I display a table which corresponds to the student record(s) he requested. So, for example, if a user enters `computerScience` for `department` text field, I should display all students in Computer Science department.

So, my SQL select statement should be able to do that at run-time.

I am using a prepared statement like this:

```
PreparedStatement pre = conn.prepareStatement("select ID,FirstName,LastName,Dept from student where ID = ? or FirstName = ? or lastName = ? or Dept = ?");
```

This however displays the result only when an ID is entered. But lets say if someone just types in "Mark" for last name and leaves every other text field blank, then this query does not display anything although there are students whose last name is Mark in the database.

Can anyone guide me here please?

Comment: Your going to need to build the statement dynamically as not every text field will have a value, for, this means a StringBuilder and List

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a dynamic query string as below (assuming minimum one criteria is prsent)

```
   String query = "select ID,FirstName,LastName,Dept from student where ";
   String delim = "";
   if(firstName != null){
      query+ = delim + "FirstName = '"+firstName+"'";
      delim = " AND ";
   }
   if(lastName != null){
      query+ = delim + "LastName = '"+lastName +"'";
      delim = " AND ";
   }
   .........
   .........
   PreparedStatement pre = conn.prepareStatement(query);
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

you can use the dynamic approach as mentioned in other comments and answer.
But in this case, since the columns themselves don't get added at runtime, another approach can also be used: change your statement to be:

```
PreparedStatement pre = conn.prepareStatement("select ID,FirstName,LastName,Dept from student where ID = IFNULL(?,ID) and FirstName = IFNULL(?,FirstName) AND lastName = IFNULL(?,lastName) and Dept = IFNULL(?,Dept)");
```

note all conditions where changed to "and" instead of "or".
to understand what is happening: lets take an example "Dept = IFNULL(?,Dept)"
here, if the value you pass is null (the user did not choose a department) then IFNULL(?,Dept) evaluates to Dept from the current row in db and the whole condition Dept = IFNULL(?,Dept) will evaluate to true as Dept is equalized with itself. otherwise, if you send a value, IFNULL(?,Dept) evaluates to that value and the row is chosen only if the dept in it is equal to that value. the same goes for other parts and thats why "and" is used.
in effect, each condition makes sure that if there is a value, the row must have the same value in order to be returned. otherwise, the condition does not block the row !!!

as a last note, you must insure that if the user selects no data in the field, you pass NULL to the db as value for that field (watch out from whitespaces). **and IF the field ID is numeric**, then you need to change the part above for it to be something like the following (and also insure you send 0 in the case user chooses no id): ID = IFNULL(NULLIF(?,0),ID)

```
PreparedStatement pre = conn.prepareStatement("select ID,FirstName,LastName,Dept from student where ID = IFNULL(NULLIF(?,0),ID) and FirstName = IFNULL(?,FirstName) AND lastName = IFNULL(?,lastName) and Dept = IFNULL(?,Dept)");
```